# Passing a lambda with return value into a callback without return value

Tags: c++11, boost, lambda, boost-asio

This question involves `boost::asio` but is a pure `C++ 11` question.

I am new to `C++ 11` & `lambda` techniques which I am trying to use with `boost::asio::async_connect` for network communication.

Following is my function which attempts an asynchronous connect with the host.

```
bool MyAsyncConnectFunction() {

  //some logic here to check validity of host
  if (ip_is_not_resolved)
    return false;

  the_socket.reset(new tcp::socket(the_io_service));
  auto my_connection_handler = [this]
        (const boost::system::error_code& errc, const tcp::resolver::iterator& itr)
  {
    if (errc) {
        //Set some variables to false as we are not connected
        return false;
    }

    //Do some stuff as we are successfully connected at this point
    return true;
  };

  //How is async_connect taking a lambda which 
  boost::asio::async_connect(the_socket, IP_destination, tcp::resolver::iterator(), my_connection_handler);
  return true;
}
```

All works fine. There are no functional issues absolutely. However, I am wondering that `boost::asio::async_connect` takes a `ConnectionHandler without a return type` in its last parameter but I am passing a lambda i.e. `my_connection_handler` which returns a value.

**How is it possible that I can pass a lambda with a return value whereas `boost::asio::async_connect`'s 4th param takes a callback without a return value ?**

Comment: the return value can be discarded as in this simple example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d451892e201ba84
the same is done in asio: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/42e7869f411a75512fb6994c634eb086fb9eb5cc/include/boost/asio/impl/connect.hpp#L258

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html#boost_asio.reference.asynchronous_operations.return_type_of_an_initiating_function

Comment: @m.s. Return values are discarded !! Does it mean that I can bind a return value based callback to a void returning callback ?  Or is this the way asio's connect_handler is written ? As I said I am newbie. Sorry if its a silly question

Comment: No it does not. It works because you do no call a function, you call a function template that expects a callable, whatever is its return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::asio::async_connect` is a function template that takes a callable as its fourth argument. It does not use the return value of said callable, nor does it care about it. Just as you could write :

```
auto f = []() { return true; };
f();  // Return value is discarded
```

The example of @m.s. is good too. Since it is a template, the function resolves the argument according to the [template argument deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).